# Linq to Sql - Double Group By with Parent Table Relation

Tags: asp.net, linq, linq-to-sql

I'm having a trouble getting a linq to sql query and was wondering if someone could help.  I have these tables: 'Orders', 'OrderProducts', 'Products' and 'Users'.  I want to get a breakdown of the count of how many products (contained in 'OrderProducts' by ProductID) each 'User' has ordered.  The User's UserID is contained in the 'Orders' table and 'OrderProducts' orderID is related to the orderID in 'Orders'.  Final results should be like this:

```
            User1   User2    User3   
Product1     100     75       17
Product2     24      78       18
Product3     82      48       35
```

So it is grouped by both UserID and ProductID and takes the sum of the qty of all grouped ProductIDs by that userID.  I hope that makes sense.  Any help is much appreciated, thanks!

Here's a simplified database breakdown:
Products
- ProductID 
- ProductName

Orders
- OrderID 
- UserID

OrderProducts 
- OrderID 
- ProductID 
- ProductQty

Users
- UserID 
- UserName

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a query that will give you a list of `Users`, `Products`, and the `Count`:

```
from op in OrderProducts
group op by new {op.Order.User, op.Product} into g
select new
{
  g.Key.User.UserName,
  g.Key.Product.ProductName,
  Count=g.Sum(op => op.ProductQty)
}
```

It won't give you results in the exact format you want, but it will get you most of the way there using only Linq.

Also take note that this won't pull any extra data - (`Users` or `Products` with counts of 0). This may or may not be what you're looking for.

[Edit]
Here's another query to take a look at (two actually):

```
from p in Products
from u in Users
let i = (from op in OrderProducts
         where op.Order.User == u && op.Product == p
         select op.ProductQty)
let quant = i.Count() == 0 ? 0 : i.Sum(v=>v)
select new {p.ProductName, u.UserName, Quantity = quant}
//group new {u.UserName, Quantity = quant} by p into g
//select new {g.Key.ProductName, Users = g.AsEnumerable()}
```

As is, this should give you straight results (table of ProductName, UserName, Quantity). The commented out portion will instead group by Product, which (depending on how you render your results) might be what you want.

Comment: Hmm, this looks promising, but I haven't gotten a chance to mess with it much.  How would I modify it to return the zeros?  (ie User has ordered this product 0 times).  In the end, I will be specifying which products and users to include in the results, so I would have to have those as 0's.  Thanks so far though!

Comment: Also, let me know if anyone has tips for cleaning up my queries!

Comment: Hey thanks man!  I've been on another project and just got back to this.  I have to do this project in VB.NET though, and I have just one issue converting your linq statement to vb.net.  I don't know what the i.Sum(v=>v) would convert to.  I've got this so far:   From p In Products _
From u In Users _
Let i = (From op In OrderProducts _
         Where op.Order.User.UserID = u.UserID And op.Product.ProductID = p.ProductID _
         Select op.ProductQty) _
Let Qty = _
         If(i.Count() = 0, 0, i.Sum()) _
Select New With {p.ProductName, u.Username, Qty}

Thanks a lot Ryan!

Comment: Use `i.Sum(Function(v) v))` instead of just the `i.Sum()`. Make sure you take a look at using the groups (commented out portion) as well in case it fits what you need more closely.

Comment: Awesome!  Thanks so much, I think you've answered a few of my questions on here now, I should just hire you, lol!  Thanks a million!

Comment: I'm happy to help when I can!

Comment: I was able to produce a similar "double group by" in T-SQL in a few minutes but it took me quite a long time to figure it out in LINQ. This answer was actually very helpful +1.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the appropriate relationships set up in the database (and therefore, in the DBML), you may want to consider something like this (UNTESTED):

```
<table>
<tr>
  <asp:Repeater ID="_users" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
      <td><%# Eval("UserName") %></td>
    </ItemTemplate>
  </asp:Repeater>
</tr>
<asp:Repeater ID="_products" runat="server">
  <ItemTemplate>
    <tr>
      <td><%# Eval("Product.ProductName") %></td>
      <asp:Repeater ID="_users" runat="server" DataSource='<%# GetUsersProducts(Eval("ProductID")) %>'>
        <ItemTemplate>
          <td><%# Eval("count") %></td>
        </ItemTemplate>
      </asp:Repeater>
   </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
</table>
```

Code-behind:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   _users.DataSource = context.Users.OrderBy(u => u.UserName);
   _users.DataBind();

   _products.DataSource = context.Products;
   _products.DataBind();
}
protected object GetUsersProducts(string ProductID)
{
  var prodord = from op in context.OrderProducts where op.ProductID == ProductID select op;
  return from u in context.Users.OrderBy(u2 => u2.UserName) select new {
    count = prodord.Where(op => op.Order.User.UserID == u.UserID).Sum(op => op.ProductQty)
  };
}
```

You will obviously want to change around your markup and some of the object types, but I'm hoping this will get you going.  I try to use the autogenerated class object structure as much as possible to avoid creating unreadable LINQ queries.

Comment: The problem with this seems to be that it will run a separate query for every product for every user.  If there's 2500 products and 500 users, thats 1.25 million trips to the database... you're going to be waiting a day for the results.

Answer (score 0):

The result shape you are asking for is known as a *pivot*.  It has columns which are data-driven, instead of columns which are declared before the query runs.

The trick here is to project the result into a type where the "properties" can vary at run-time.  I did something like that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/320895/using-linq-to-create-crosstab-results)

Here's a stab at your particular problem:

```
// grab relationally-shaped results from database
var queryResult = 
(
  from u in myDataContext.Users
  from o in u.Orders
  from op in o.OrderProducts
  select new
  {
    UserName = u.UserName,
    ProductName = op.ProductName,
    Quantity = op.Quantity
  }
).ToList()

// now use a LinqToObjects query to pivot
List<XElement> pivotedResults =
(
  from x in queryResult
  group by x.ProductName into g
  select new XElement(g.Key,
    from y in g
    group by y.UserName into subg
    select new XAttribute(subg.Key, subg.Sum(z => z.Quantity))
).ToList();
```