# Dynamic Pivot Linq C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I have the following collection / table

```
Category    Type       Detail     Cost

Auto        Hybrid     AC         80
Auto        Hybrid     Sunroof    100
Auto        Standard   AC         120
Motorcycle  Standard   Radio      60
```

Is there a way with linq to get this to pivot to look like this?

```
Category     Type      AC     Radio    Sunroof     
Auto         Hybrid    80     0        100 
Auto         Standard  120    0        0
Motorcycle   Standard  0      60       0
```

The details are dynamic so I can't hard code the value in the linq.

Comment: [Pivot data using LINQ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/963491/pivot-data-using-linq)

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "the details are dynamic"?

Comment: I mean a new detail could be added to the table at any time, so the linq would have to include the new detail as a column

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to Pivot data using LINQ?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/167304/is-it-possible-to-pivot-data-using-linq)

Answer (score 2):

use the `let` keyword to generate a key for use with the `group by` clause like so:

```
var query = from item in list
            let key = new { Category = item.Category, Type = item.Type }
            group new { Detail = item.Detail, Cost = item.Cost } by key;
```

you can loop through the items returned from the query like so:

```
foreach(var item in query) {
    Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}: ", item.Key.Category, item.Key.Type);
    foreach(var detail in item) {
        Console.WriteLine("\t{0} {1}", detail.Detail, detail.Cost);
    }
}
```

it displays the following output

```
Auto Hybrid:
        AC 80
        Sunroof 100
Auto Standard:
        AC 120
Motorcycle Standard:
        Radio 60
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! I'm working with your query to end up outputting a source that will bind to a gridview as in my example.

Comment: Do you know of an easy way to do this Charles? I suppose I could just create a datatable within the for each statements you have there.

Comment: If you are avoiding changing the UI control when more Detail values are added, then yes, you are going to have to dynamically create your control. You might look at the `Aggregate` method and pass in a `new GridView()` as the seed, and build it in there. That might be easier than using the loops. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549218.aspx