# LINQ to SQL Grouping and Counting

Tags: c#, linq, c#-4.0, grouping, counting

I have searched for solution, but nothing similar.
My problem is that I want to select data from database, group it by UserID and Count it by Status id

Users

```
UserID
Name
```

Appointments

```
UserID
ClientID
Status
StartDate
```

Status can be active=1, canceled=2, done=3

This is how I will display results.

[image: Results table]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You're actually pivoting the data here; not something linq is great at but this might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/963491/pivot-data-using-linq

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In you question you say you want to group on `UserId`, but in the output you show `Name`. This query will group on both. You might want to adjust it to your needs.

```
from u in tblUsers
join a in tblAppointments on u.UserID equals a.UserID
group a by new { u.UserID, u.Name } into g
select new
{
    Name     = g.Key.Name,
    Active   = g.Count (x => x.Status == 1),
    Canceled = g.Count (x => x.Status == 2),
    Done     = g.Count (x => x.Status == 3)
}
```

(this will handle the case if two users have the same name though)

Answer (score 0):

[This covers grouping operators](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/LINQ-to-DataSets-Grouping-c62703ea).  [This covers the count.](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b)