# dynamically transpose list object

Tags: c#, list, linq

I have list of workItemStateCalculatedTimes as below

```
public class WorkItemStateCalculatedTime
{
    public string State { get; set; }
    public double TimeinHrs { get; set; }
}
```

[image]

and need to transpose it to get below desired output where first column value of each row will be converted as column and timeinhrs will be value for that column

[image]

State column can have multiple rows. I tried to use dynamic list but not getting desired output.

```
List<dynamic> data = new List<dynamic>();
foreach (var item in workItemStateCalculatedTimes)
{
    data.Add(item.State);
}
```

Comment: So, the final result, would be like, `data` that has `data.New`, `data.Todo` & `data.Done`, with the value of `data.New` being `4.6` etc?

Comment: @Martheen yes I need result list like this

Comment: What does "State column can have multiple rows" mean?

Comment: @Enigmativity It can have 3 columns as shown sometime it can have 4 or 5 with other values like in progress, in review.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/25633527/861716

Comment: The biggest question would be, what are you going to do with the result? How are you going to work with the transposed list? Do you want to do further calculations, visualize it or what? Depending on your next step it really depends which model to use for the transposition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done using [ExpandoObject](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.dynamic.expandoobject), adding the columns then converting the object into dynamic.

```
var calculated = new[] { new {State = "New",TimeinHrs = 4.6 }, new { State = "Todo", TimeinHrs = 5.4 }, new { State = "Done", TimeinHrs = 8.5 } }.ToList();
var expTransposed = new ExpandoObject();
calculated.ForEach(c => expTransposed.TryAdd(c.State, c.TimeinHrs));
dynamic dynTransposed = expTransposed;
Console.WriteLine(dynTransposed.New); //would output 4.6
```

You can still loop through all the columns with `expTransposed`.

Comment: I am getting error "the call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties : 'system.collection.generic.collectionextension.TryAdd and system.collection.generic.Dictionaryextension.TryAdd'"

Comment: What is the type of State and TimeinHrs, your .NET version and the included namespaces? I can't replicate that ambiguous call https://dotnetfiddle.net/EcFoJb

Comment: They're the same member types as my anonymous example, and as you can see in the fiddle I don't encounter the ambiguous call

Comment: I was getting the error due to Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Common.dll conflict. I used inline reference of dll and problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

I got something like this, do check it once.

```
public class WorkItemStateCalculatedTime
{
    public string State { get; set; }
    public double TimeinHrs { get; set; }
}

public class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        List<WorkItemStateCalculatedTime> workItemStateCalculatedTimes = new List<WorkItemStateCalculatedTime>
        {
            new WorkItemStateCalculatedTime { State = "New", TimeinHrs = 2.5 },
            new WorkItemStateCalculatedTime { State = "ToDo", TimeinHrs = 3.0 },
            new WorkItemStateCalculatedTime { State = "Done", TimeinHrs = 1.5 },
            new WorkItemStateCalculatedTime { State = "WIP", TimeinHrs = 4.5 },
        };

        var distinctStates = workItemStateCalculatedTimes.Select(w => w.State).Distinct().ToList();

        DataTable transposedTable = new DataTable();

        foreach (var state in distinctStates)
        {
            transposedTable.Columns.Add(state, typeof(double));
        }

        var groupedData = workItemStateCalculatedTimes.GroupBy(w => w.State);

        foreach (var group in groupedData)
        {
            DataRow newRow = transposedTable.NewRow();
            newRow[group.Key] = group.Sum(w => w.TimeinHrs);
            transposedTable.Rows.Add(newRow);
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Transposed Data:");
        foreach (DataRow row in transposedTable.Rows)
        {
            Console.Write("State: ");
            foreach (var state in distinctStates)
            {
                Console.Write($"{state}: {row[state]}  ");
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
    }
}
```

[image]