# Linq Count number of consults per week, from 28 weeks in the past till current week

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a sql table named Consult it represents consults(treatments) of physical therapists

```
ConsultID ConsultDate Therapist Location
```

I want to present this data summarized per week, starting 28 weeks ago till current week

Like:

```
Location     Week-1          Week-2          Week-3 .....      Week-28
Amsterdam    41              38              34                55

Utrecht      65              56              46                46
```

How can I do this in Linq? I have the following:

```
public ActionResult Therapist(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }

        DateTime startDate = DateTime.Now.StartOfWeek(DayOfWeek.Monday).AddDays(-168);
        DateTime endDate = DateTime.Now.StartOfWeek(DayOfWeek.Sunday);

        var TherapistConsult = from row in db.Consults
                               where ((row.Therapist == id) && (row.ConsultDate > startDate) && (row.ConsultDate < endDate))
                                 group row by row.Location into g
                                 where g.FirstOrDefault() != null
                                 select new
                                 {
                                     Location = g.Key,
                                     // Need a loop here for 28 weeks in the past till this week
                                     // WeekN = g.Count(x => x.Week == N),

                                 };

        return View(TherapistConsult.ToList());

    }
```

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: yes, i have the following: var tr = from row in Consults
       where ((row.Therapist == 44) && (row.ConsultDate > Convert.ToDateTime("19-5-2014 00:00:00") && (row.ConsultDate < Convert.ToDateTime("2-11-2014 00:00:00"))))
                            group row by row.Location into g
       where g.FirstOrDefault() != null
                            select new
                    {
                            Location = g.Key, Week-1 = g.Count (x => x.Week == 1 )

Comment: Group By `ConsultDate` and then select all from there on.

Comment: Does your week start on a monday or on a sunday or is "week-1" just "today - 7 days"?

Comment: Week starts at Monday, for startDate and enddate i have: DateTime endDate = DateTime.Now.StartOfWeek(DayOfWeek.Sunday);
            DateTime startDate = DateTime.Now.StartOfWeek(DayOfWeek.Monday).AddDays(-168);

Comment: `select new { Week - 1 = ...}` isn't going to work, `Week - 1` isn't a valid property name. Try something like `WeekNumber`. Please show the actual code you use, what you expect it to do and what it actually does.

Comment: to get the week number you can use the `datepart(wk, your_datetime_field)`

Comment: if you want I can tell you the sql query but can not provide you the Linq

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're looking for is "Pivoting" your data, which is much easier to do from SQL then from linq,
Look this up in CodeProject
http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/500811/Simple-Way-To-Use-Pivot-In-SQL-Query
And if you *have* to do this in linq for some reason, look this up:
[Pivot data using LINQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/963491/pivot-data-using-linq)