# Linq Group by to column

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list of items with a property **code** and I want to group by **eventId** and create a table representation where code values are transformed to columns.
Every triple (event, code,amount) is unique.

I want to transform this

```
eventId code  amount  
  1      A     100
  1      B     101
  1      C     102
  2      A     103
  2      C     104
  3      B     105
  ....
```

to this

```
eventId  A    B   C
 1      100  101 102
 2      103   0  104
 3       0   105  0
 ... 


var table=from x in list
    group x by x.eventId into gr
    select new
           {
              eventId=gr.Key,
              ....
           }
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to filter on grouped result and project in to anonymous object :

```
var table=from x in list
    group x by x.eventId into gr
    select new
           {
              eventId=gr.Key,
              A = gr.Where(x=>x.code == "A").Sum(x=>x.amount),
              B = gr.Where(x=>x.code == "B").Sum(x=>x.amount),
              C = gr.Where(x=>x.code == "C").Sum(x=>x.amount)
           }
```

Comment: Thank you, I don't know the codes from the beginning

Comment: then you would need to group on the `code` as well

Comment: then what's inside select (no need to display the sum, every triple is unique).?

Comment: i will update my post to show how you can do that

Comment: have a look at : http://stackoverflow.com/a/963755/1875256

Answer (score 0):

It's actually quite neat to use a lookup:

```
var table =
    from x in list
    group x by x.eventId into gr
    let lookup = gr.ToLookup(y => y.code, y => y.amount)
    select new
    {
        eventId = gr.Key,
        A = lookup["A"].Sum(),
        B = lookup["B"].Sum(),
        C = lookup["C"].Sum(),
    };
```

I get this result:

[image: query]