# Multiple SUM using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, aggregate-functions

I have a loop like the following, can I do the same using multiple SUM?

```
foreach (var detail in ArticleLedgerEntries.Where(pd => pd.LedgerEntryType == LedgerEntryTypeTypes.Unload &&
                                                                pd.InventoryType == InventoryTypes.Finished))
{
     weight += detail.GrossWeight;
     length += detail.Length;
     items  += detail.NrDistaff;
}
```

Comment: LINQ is not the be-all and end-all of data manipulation, and there's still nothing wrong with a for loop.

Comment: Funny though @SLaks that this is one of the rare cases where LINQ doesn't offer a reasonable solution.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Technically speaking, what you have is probably the most efficient way to do what you are asking. However, you could create an extension method on IEnumerable<T> called Each that might make it simpler:

```
public static class EnumerableExtensions
{
    public static void Each<T>(this IEnumerable<T> col, Action<T> itemWorker)
    {
        foreach (var item in col)
        {
            itemWorker(item);
        }
    }
}
```

And call it like so:

```
// Declare variables in parent scope
double weight;
double length;
int items;

ArticleLedgerEntries
    .Where(
        pd => 
           pd.LedgerEntryType == LedgerEntryTypeTypes.Unload &&
           pd.InventoryType == InventoryTypes.Finished
    )
    .Each(
        pd => 
        {
            // Close around variables defined in parent scope
            weight += pd.GrossWeight; 
            lenght += pd.Length;
            items += pd.NrDistaff;
        }
    );
```

UPDATE:
Just one additional note. The above example relies on a closure. The variables weight, length, and items should be declared in a parent scope, allowing them to persist beyond each call to the itemWorker action. I've updated the example to reflect this for clarity sake.

Comment: +1, nice answer. Note, that *MoreLinq* already have a `ForEach` extension method, declared for `IEnumerable<T>`. Another note, Eric Lippert [doesn't like this idea](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/05/18/foreach-vs-foreach.aspx)

Answer (score 5):

You can call `Sum` three times, but it will be slower because it will make three loops.

For example:

```
var list = ArticleLedgerEntries.Where(pd => pd.LedgerEntryType == LedgerEntryTypeTypes.Unload
                                   && pd.InventoryType == InventoryTypes.Finished))

var totalWeight = list.Sum(pd => pd.GrossWeight);
var totalLength = list.Sum(pd => pd.Length);
var items = list.Sum(pd => pd.NrDistaff);
```

Because of delayed execution, it will also re-evaluate the `Where` call every time, although that's not such an issue in your case.  This could be avoided by calling `ToArray`, but that will cause an array allocation.  (And it would still run three loops)

However, unless you have a very large number of entries or are running this code in a tight loop, you don't need to worry about performance.

---

**EDIT**: If you *really* want to use LINQ, you could misuse `Aggregate`, like this:

```
int totalWeight, totalLength, items;

list.Aggregate((a, b) => { 
    weight += detail.GrossWeight;
    length += detail.Length;
    items  += detail.NrDistaff;
    return a;
});
```

This is phenomenally ugly code, but should perform almost as well as a straight loop.

You could also sum in the accumulator, (see example below), but this would allocate a temporary object for every item in your list, which is a dumb idea.  (Anonymous types are immutable)

```
var totals = list.Aggregate(
    new { Weight = 0, Length = 0, Items = 0},
    (t, pd) => new { 
        Weight = t.Weight + pd.GrossWeight,
        Length = t.Length + pd.Length,
        Items = t.Items + pd.NrDistaff
    }
);
```

Comment: Ok. I realize that there isn't an easy way to do this using LINQ. I'll take may foreach loop because I understood that it isn't so bad.
Thanks to all of you.

Comment: Can you please comment on the answer by user805138? What does the performance look like in his approach?

Comment: @gisek: The `group x by 1` is completely useless and very stupid; it introduces LINQ syntax for no reason at all.  Other than that, it's identical to my first code; it uses two extra loops.

Comment: Is this supported by linq to entities ?

Comment: @Jayantha: I assume you're asking about the `Aggregate` mis-usages.  The first one certainly isn't (block lambdas cannot become expression trees); the second one almost definitely isn't.

Answer (score 3):

You could also group by true - 1 (which is actually including any of the items and then have them counted or summered):

```
 var results = from x in ArticleLedgerEntries
                       group x by 1
                       into aggregatedTable
                       select new
                                  {
                                      SumOfWeight = aggregatedTable.Sum(y => y.weight),
                                      SumOfLength = aggregatedTable.Sum(y => y.Length),
                                      SumOfNrDistaff = aggregatedTable.Sum(y => y.NrDistaff)
                                  };
```

As far as Running time, it is almost as good as the loop (with a constant addition).

Comment: The `group by` is completely useless and rather confusing.  Just do `var results = new { ... = ArticleLedgerEntries.Sum(...), ... }`

Answer (score 0):

You'd be able to do this pivot-style, using the answer in this topic: [Is it possible to Pivot data using LINQ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/167304/is-it-possible-to-pivot-data-using-linq)

Answer (score 0):

Ok. I realize that there isn't an easy way to do this using LINQ. I'll take may foreach loop because I understood that it isn't so bad. Thanks to all of you

Comment: You should not post an answer on SO like you would post a reply on a topic in a forum. Only do this if you answer your own question. Usually you add *UPDATE* to your original question as a sort of reply to the answers and comments on your question.