# Query to sum on grouped field

Tags: linq, sum, linq-group

I've a list of tasks. Ie I've struct like

```
struct Task
{
    public DateTime Completed { get; set; }
    public string TaskKind { get; set; }
    public float Effort { get; set; }
}
```

And I've a IList<Task>.

Now I want to group the tasks based on the date and group by TaskKind on each day with the summed effort.
For eg for I want to print like the below:

```
01-09-09     Design:10     Coding:5    Coordination:15
02-09-09     Coding:5       Meeting:2
```

Can anyone help me in constructing a LINQ query to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a combination of a simple aggregate (COUNT by TaskKind) and a PIVOT.  Take a look at this question: [Is it possible to Pivot data using LINQ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/167304/is-it-possible-to-pivot-data-using-linq)