# LINQ Pivot with dynamic columns

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, pivot

I'm trying to create a Pivot using LINQ with dynamic columns. I have created a Pivot in SQL Server where you do not know which columns are going to get used. But don't know how to transfer that into LINQ.
 Does anyone have links for me to get started on?

Cheers

Comment: What is a dynamic pivot?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to Pivot data using LINQ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/167304/is-it-possible-to-pivot-data-using-linq)

Answer (score 1):

```
    List<CustData> myList = GetCustData();

    var query = myList
        .GroupBy(c => c.CustId)
        .Select(g => new {
            CustId = g.Key,
            Jan = g.Where(c => c.OrderDate.Month == 1).Sum(c => c.Qty),
            Feb = g.Where(c => c.OrderDate.Month == 2).Sum(c => c.Qty),
            March = g.Where(c => c.OrderDate.Month == 3).Sum(c => c.Qty)
        });
```

this is the answer from [David B](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8155/david-b) in this [url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/167304/is-it-possible-to-pivot-data-using-linq)

Comment: That's not dynamic though. This (from the example you highlight in the other question) depends on knowing the columns Jan, Feb & March.