# How do I extract and combine a list of n lists?

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list which itself contains n lists (in this instance there are 4).  What I need to do is get an output as in 'required query result' below

List of lists:

```
Product      Year    DY
Comp         1992    110.0 
Comp         1993    200.0 
Non-Comp     1990    45.2 
Non-Comp     1991    50.0 
Non-Comp     1992    55.0 
Non-Comp     1993    100.0 

Product      Year    DY
Comp         1992    170.0 
Non-Comp     1990    64.8 
Non-Comp     1991    75.0 
Non-Comp     1992    85.0 

Product      Year    DY
Non-Comp     1991    25.0 

Product      Year    DY
Non-Comp     1990    37.0
```

Required query result:

```
Product      Year    DY1     DY2     DY3     DY4
Comp         1992    110.0  170.0       
Comp         1993    200.0          
Non-Comp     1990    45.2   64.8             37.0
Non-Comp     1991    50.0   75.0     25.0   
Non-Comp     1992    55.0   85.0        
Non-Comp     1993    100.0
```

Remember there could be more than 4 lists in the list so I have imagined something like:

```
foreach (var element in myList)
{
    // some hard work
}
```

Comment: What have you attempted so far?

Comment: What is the type of myList?  IEnumerable<T> (what is T)

Comment: Try not be be directly spoon fed. Share with us your attempts (and probably frustrations too)

Comment: Ready up on / google LINQ GroupBy (you'll want to group by `new { Year DY1 }` and also IEnumerable<T>.SelectMany

Comment: So, you want it to combine them such that the product/year is the key each time, correct?

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to answer this without a better description of your input/output object-model, but I think you want to:

1. Flatten your list of lists of item into a single (flat) sequence of items.
2. Group those items with a complex key comprising an item's Product and Year.
3. Project the items in each group to their respective DYs.

Something like:

```
var query = myListOfLists.SelectMany(list => list) // Flatten
                         .GroupBy(item => new { item.Product, item.Year }, // Group
                                  item => item.DY); // Project
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do it by using `LINQ`

Please check the following link:

[Is it possible to Pivot data using LINQ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/167304/is-it-possible-to-pivot-data-using-linq)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
List<List<Product>> nestedList;

List<Product> = allProducts = nestedList.SelectMany(x => x);
var groupped = allProducts
  .GroupBy(x => new { Product = x.Product, Year = x.Year}, x => x.DY );
```