# dynamically populating column headers in a gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, vb.net

I have a vb.net website with a gridview that currently has exam questions displaying vertically in each row like this:

```
Name  question  answer
-----------------------
Joe   question1 answer1
Joe   question2 answer2
Joe   question3 answer3
Jill  question1 answer1
Jill  question2 answer2
Jill  question3 answer3
```

But I would like to change it, so that each question is a header, like this:

```
Name question1 question2 question3
----------------------------------
Joe  answer1   answer2   answer3
Jill answer1   answer2   answer3
```

This makes it more readable since each user is only listed once.

I've spent the better part of the morning googling for solutions, but really can't find anything that works.

I would like to stick with a gridview instead of rewriting all my code.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

I am actually binding my data to the gridview via some other programmers class. I am using LINQ like this:

```
Return (From entry In report.FetchAllEntries()
                Select questionID = entry.Question.QuestionID,
                userID = entry.Session.User.ID,
                firstName = entry.Session.User.FirstName,
                lastName = entry.Session.User.LastName,
                QuestionText = entry.Question.Stem,
                UserResponse = entry.Response.Text,
                FreeResponse = entry.ResponseText,
                SessionDate = entry.Timestamp
                 Where SessionDate.HasValue AndAlso
                               SessionDate.Value >= dateField1 AndAlso
                               SessionDate.Value <= dateField2
                Order By lastName, SessionDate, questionID
```

Thanks

Comment: It looks like you might be able to do that by modifying your SQL query (like doing a `PIVOT` or something).  Can you show the query that's generating the data for your `GridView`?

Comment: I am binding via a LINQ statement.  I am not sure if I can modify the LINQ statement to switch it around like that...I edited my original post to include the LINQ. --Thanks

Comment: You might be able to pivot the data from using another linq query: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/167304/is-it-possible-to-pivot-data-using-linq

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use group by to aggregate your results. This should work:

```
Dim grouped =
    From usersAnswers In
        From result In results
        Group result By result.userID Into Group
        Let answers = Group.OrderBy(Function(x) x.QuestionText).ToList()
        Select
            answers.First().firstName,
            Question1 = answers(0).UserResponse,
            Question2 = answers(1).UserResponse,
            Question3 = answers(2).UserResponse
```