# how to generate dynamic table using datatable and datarow in c# below i have mentioned table format which i am expecting

Tags: c#, ado.net

[image: Sample table structure]

i want to generate the dynamic table from A-table to B-table,by using normal C#,ADO.net
is it possible?if it is, how we can write logic for this.

Comment: DataTable tutorial http://www.dotnetperls.com/datatable

Answer (score 0):

This article explains how to do what you are asking:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/44274/Transpose-a-DataTable-using-C

And this SO question is also answered quite nicely:

[Restructuring (transposing) datatable in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18274035/restructuring-transposing-datatable-in-c-sharp)