# Linq pivot query, data in column becomes column header

Tags: linq-to-sql, pivot

I have the following set of data:
[image]

That I need to pivot on the SupplierPartNumber so the Attribute becomes the column header:
[image]

I can do it in SQL (the results pictured above) but I can't figure out how this would be translated in to LINQ.  Can anyone offer some advise on how this could be done?  The initial set of data is required so I can keep the result set in memory and query other columns like attribute type on the same page without querying the database any further.

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to Pivot data using LINQ?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/167304/is-it-possible-to-pivot-data-using-linq)

Comment: Bluefeet, that's different as I don't know how many attributes I will get back.  That has the key column and then 3 others explicitly defined.  Thanks anyway