# Is it possible to rewrite this SQL query in LINQ format? I'm not sure how I would use pivots in LINQ

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-sql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it possible to Pivot data using LINQ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/167304/is-it-possible-to-pivot-data-using-linq)

I'm just starting to get into using LINQ inside of my C# projects instead of using stored procedures in my database. Im a LINQ rookie.

What would this SQL query look like in LINQ format?

```
SELECT Month,
    [1] VideoCount,
    [2] GameCount,
    [3] FlashCount,
    [4] PictureCount,
    [5] JokeCount
FROM 
(
    SELECT MediaTypeID, DATENAME(m, MediaDate) Month
    FROM Media
    WHERE DATEPART(YEAR, MediaDate) = 2012
) src
PIVOT
(
    COUNT(MediaTypeID)
    FOR MediaTypeID IN ([1], [2], [3], [4], [5])
) piv
ORDER BY MONTH(Month +' 1900')
```

My Table looks like:

[image]

And my SQL results look like:

[image]

Comment: Need more information such as which object are you wanting to perform the query on? Are  you wanting to use an extension method?

Comment: Check this stack post:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/167304/is-it-possible-to-pivot-data-using-linq

Comment: You did ask the SQL question last night. I'd strongly suggest you to do this that way, even if you are not familiar with T-SQL.

Comment: Mohammad, I did. Im calling the query inside of my project using var Results = DB.Database.SqlQuery<MonthlyMediaCounts>(SQL); where SQL is the query text. Since the query is inside my project I thought it might be better to be written as LINQ? I'm not sure though.