# list of sums to new list

Tags: c#, linq, math

I have a list of items with a total value in each item..
Some are in a different layer.. As shown below

```
**Name, Layer, Value**
Item 1, Layer1, 100
Item 1, Layer1, 200
Item 1, Layer2, 700
```

Now
I want to combine these into a new list, and merge them together.. As shown below

```
**Name, List(Layer1Value, Layer2Value)**
Item 1, (300,700)
```

This is the code I have so far..

```
List<double> = 
Enumerable.Range(0, t.Select(u => u.LayerName).Distinct().Count())
.Select(idx => t.Select(a => a.sum).Sum()).ToList()
```

This of course is wrong and puts the totals in all the value spots..
like this

```
Item 1, (1000,1000)
```

Unsure how to get it to work correct, any help would be great..
Thanks

---

Added help..
Starting with a list like this

```
private class Items
{
    public string Name;
    public string Layer;
    public double Value;
}

List<Items> MyItems = new List<Items>();
```

To a list like this

```
private class CombinedItems
{
    public string Name;
    public List<double> LayerValues;
}

List<CombinedItems> MyCombinedItems = new List<CombinedItems>();
```

---

It should output in a specific order..
Example, If there are 4 Layers..
Layer1, Layer2, Layer3, Layer4..

And item1 has values in Layer1, and Layer 4..
then the

**List needs to be as (Layer1Value, 0, 0, Layer4Value)**

Comment: Please post the code describing the source list. Your explanation doesnt translate to code very easily.

Comment: Have a gander at 'GroupBy'.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/167304/is-it-possible-to-pivot-data-using-linq/167937#167937

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
list.GroupBy(x => x.Name)
    .Select(g => new {
          Name = g.Key,
          Elements = g.GroupBy(x => x.Layer)
                      .Select(g => g.Sum(z => z.Value))
       });
```

Edit :

```
var layers = list.Select(x => x.Layer).Distinct().OrderBy(x => x);
var result = list.GroupBy(x => x.Name)
                .Select(g => new
                {
                    Name = g.Key,
                    Values = layers.Select(x =>  g.Where(n => n.Layer == x)
                                                  .Sum(z => z.Value))
                });
```

Comment: I will test it, but I am unsure if this will allow for a certain instance..  Example if there are 3 Layers, but the item only has 2 layers to it.. will it have (Layer1Value, 0, Layer3Value)  for example.. anyway gonna test

Comment: @ChrisFazzio no it will have `Layer1Value`, `Layer3Value`. If that's not what you want, you should mention this.

Comment: My fault for lack of information.. This is my real problem though.. To get the values in this order.. See the explanation at the bottom of my post that I added..