# How can i use cross Tab Query in c# linq?

Tags: c#, linq

```
var TatalFeeCollectionDetail = new List<lcclsTotalFeeCollectionDetail>();
TatalFeeCollectionDetail = (from t in .......
                            group t by new { t.MonthName,t.FeeParticularName }                                        
                                into grp                                           
                                select new lcclsTotalFeeCollectionDetail                                           
                                {
                                    Month = grp.Key.MonthName,
                                    Particular = grp.First().FeeParticularLedgerName,
                                    Amount = grp.Sum(t => t.Amount),
                                }).ToList();
dgvTotalFeeCollectionDetail.DataSource = TatalFeeCollectionDetail;
```

My result is this .............

```
    Month   particular Amount   
    April       b      1    
    April       c      2    
    April       d      1    
    April       e      2
    April       f      1
```

I want to convert it like this can any1 help me...........I search for it but can,t understood what to do....

```
Month   b   c   d   e   f   Total Amount
April   1   2   1   2   1       7
```

Thanxxxxxxx in advance

Comment: Nice question, I am also looking for the same.

Comment: May help : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/167304/is-it-possible-to-pivot-data-using-linq

Comment: i Cant Get Anything Useful From above links..........I want do add columns Dynamically .......

Comment: @SandeepSinghHada well, and if you have many months in your result, and different 'particular' for each month what do you want to get, then ? (for example, you have results for `b, c, d` in `April` and results for `d, e, f` for `May` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't. That would mean creating an anonymous type with a variable number of properties, and it's not possible in C# which is strongly typed.

What you can certainly do is storing the 'particular' values in a Dictionary and get a result like

```
Month     particular                                  Total
April     {{b, 1}, {c, 2}, {d, 1}, {e, 2}, {f, 1}}    7
```

Answer (score 0):

Nearly nine years after asking:
You Could try a GroupJoin in a GroupBy

```
string[] particulars = TatalFeeCollectionDetail.Select(x => x.FeeParticularName ).Distinct().ToArray();
var crossTabbedData=TatalFeeCollectionDetail.GroupBy(TFCD => TFCD.Month).Select(TFCD => new {Month=TFCD.Key,RowData=particulars.GroupJoin(TFCD, p => p, t => t.FeeParticularName, (p, t) => t.Count() == 0 ? 0 : t.Sum(fn => fn.Amount)).ToList()}).ToList();
```

Should produce something like what you want, but perhaps without column headers.