# Pivot datatable based on key and value in datatable

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

the data i am having is like, i am trying this from week am not able to find any solution.
I need to do this using either pivot using c# or using lists. Kindly provide the answers. immediate.

```
 Key  Value
 A    e
 B    f
 C    i
 D    j
 A    k 
 B    l 
 C    m
 D    n
```

i need something like this

```
 A B C D
 -------
 e f i j
 k l m n
```

where the first line is a column header.

Any better link of any stackoverflow question also appreciable.

By following code am able to get distinct columns, now problem is with assigning values in rows.
please provide any better way of doing this.

```
   foreach (DataRow row in dtBackupData.Rows)
    {
        keyname = row["KeyName"].ToString(); 
        if (!keyNameList.Contains(keyname))
        {                
            keyNameList.Add(keyname);
            dtDynamic.Columns.Add(keyname, typeof(string));               
        }            
    }
```

Comment: Try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/167304/is-it-possible-to-pivot-data-using-linq/167937#167937 answer,
Hope it will help you

  [1]:

Comment: coloumns will be dynamic.

Comment: it wasnt useful for my case