# EntityFramework / LinQ load entity from database to dto

Tags: c#, database, linq, entity-framework

I have a problem loading the correct data to a DTO using EF and linq.

From my DB I receive following example data:

```
1, 1, 1

1, 1, 2

1, 1, 3

2, 1, 4

2, 1, 5
```

etc.

I want to load these data in a DTO which should look like this:

```
int, int, ICollection<int>
```

so for the example data:

```
new MyDto(1, 1, new List<int> { 1, 2, 3 });
new MyDto(2, 1, new List<int> { 4, 5 });
```

This is my linq query

```
var result = (from adresses in context.Adress
              join person in context.Person on adresses.PersonId equals person.Id
              select new MyObj { Id1 = adresses.Id1, Id2 = adresses.Id2, PersonId = person.Id })
```

But it is wrong, since it doesn't group by Id1 and Id2 and doesn't put the personIds in the list...

Could you please tell me how I can achieve this?

Comment: you can use the LINQ `group by` statement.

Comment: Hi Steven, thanks for your post. I thought that it could be achieved with `group by`, but I couldn't get it to work. I have never really used linq before, so if you could give me a hint how to do it I would be very thankful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the good answers of you guys, I could finally work it out :-)

```
var result = from tuple in (from address in context.Adresses
                            join person in context.Persons on address.PersonId equals person.Id
             select new { person.Id, address.Id1, address.Id2})
             group tuple by new { tuple.Id1, tuple.Id2 } into myGrouping
             select 
                 new MyObj 
                     { 
                         Id1 = myGrouping.Key.Id1,
                         Id2 = myGrouping.Key.Id2,
                         PersonIds = myGrouping.Select(x => x.PersonId).Distinct()
                     };
```

Answer (score 1):

Pivot data using Linq is a better way. You can take look at this link:

[Is it possible to Pivot data using LINQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/167304/is-it-possible-to-pivot-data-using-linq)

To answer your question, below is an example:

```
var result = (from adresses in context.Adress
              join person in context.Person on adresses.PersonId equals person.Id
              group address by address.Id1 into gResult
              select new{
                Id1 = gResult.Key,
                Id2 = gResult.Select(r => r.Id2).FirstOrDefault (),
                Id3 = gResult.Select (r => r.Id3)
              });
```

Answer (score 0):

In your Address class, do you have a property for a Person instance so you're able to set up a relationship between the two classes?  If so, the following query may get you the result set that you're looking for:

```
public class Address 
{
   public int Id1 { get; set; }
   public int Id2 { get; set; }
   public virtual Person Person { get; set; }
}

public void Foo() 
{
   IEnumerable<MyObj> = context.Address.Select(x => new {
                                                           Id1 = x.Id1,
                                                           Id2 = x.Id2,
                                                           PersonId = x.Person.Id 
                                                         });
}
```

Comment: Hey NuNn DaDdY thank you for your answer, but I only have a `int PersonId` field on the address. I think your answer would work, if PersonId of the DTO would be a `int` but as I wrote in my question, it's a `ICollection<int>`

The DTO looks like this:

`public class MyDto
    {
        public long? Id1 { get; set; }

        public long? Id2 { get; set; }

        public ICollection<int> PersonIds { get; set; }
    }`