# Pivot table in Linq

Tags: c#, linq, pivot

I know you cannot cannot directly use the tSQL PIVOT function in Linq, but I cannot get the correct Linq syntax for what I feel is a simple transform (which I can do in straight tSQL)

I need to take this data set:

[image: before pivot]

and pivot it into this:
[image: after pivot]

Can someone please help me with the correct Linq syntax?

Here's how I can accomplish this in tSQL (both using PIVOT() and not)

```
 Select piv.* from (
  select custom_data_key, custom_data_value from dbo.kb_article_custom_data cd
 inner join dbo.kb_article kb on cd.article_id = kb.article_id
 where (custom_data_key='article_problem' or custom_data_key = 'article_cause' or custom_data_key='article_solution') and article_number='AKB26'
 ) d
 pivot
 (max(custom_data_value) for custom_data_key in([article_problem],[article_cause], [article_solution])) piv;
```

--WITHOUT USING PIVOT()

```
select 
 max(case when t.[custom_data_key]='article_problem' then t.[custom_data_value] end) as Article_problem,
  max(case when t.[custom_data_key]='article_cause' then t.[custom_data_value] end) as Article_cause,
   max(case when t.[custom_data_key]='article_solution' then t.[custom_data_value] end) as Article_solution
 from(select custom_data_key, custom_data_value from dbo.kb_article_custom_data cd
 inner join dbo.kb_article kb on cd.article_id = kb.article_id
 where (custom_data_key='article_problem' or custom_data_key = 'article_cause' or custom_data_key='article_solution') and article_number='AKB26')t
```

This LINQ statement will get me the results in the first image above:

```
var query = 
                        from a in custdata
                        join b in kbase on a.article_id equals b.article_id
                        where (a.custom_data_key == "article_problem" || a.custom_data_key == "article_cause" || a.custom_data_key == "article_solution") && b.article_number == id
                        select new { Key = a.custom_data_key, Value = a.custom_data_value };
```

Here's what is failing. I take the results of the Linq query above-

```
var q2 = from row in  query
                     group row by "Value" into g
                     select new TO_Kbase
                     {
                         Problem= g.Where(c => c.Key =="article_problem" ).Select(c => c.Value).ToString(),
                         Cause = g.Where(c => c.Key =="article_cause").Select(c => c.Value).ToString(),
                         Solution = g.Where(c => c.Key =="article_solution").Select(c => c.Value).ToString()
                     };
            foreach(var x in q2)
            {
                TO_Kbase kb = new TO_Kbase();
                kb.Problem =x.Problem;
                kb.Cause = x.Cause;
                kb.Solution = x.Solution;
                ta.Add(kb);

            }
```

The output is this:

```
Problem: System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.Implementation.ObjectMaterializer`1+d__0`1[System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader,System.String] 
Cause: System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.Implementation.ObjectMaterializer`1+d__0`1[System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader,System.String] 
Solution: System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.Implementation.ObjectMaterializer`1+d__0`1[System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader,System.String]
```

Comment: Would this work maybe? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/167304/is-it-possible-to-pivot-data-using-linq

Comment: Can you share that *straight tSQL* you're talking about?

Comment: @ahwm thank you for the very quick reply.  I've been reading that exact article for an hour and I cannot implement the Linq correctly.

Comment: @MarcinJ I've added the SQL above.

Comment: I dont have a direct answer for you, sorry.   But it looks like you are using your data for presentation... you may try one of the third party control libraries.  I have recent experience with DevExpress pivot grid and I can tell you its world class and very easy to use and will almost certainly work for you based on what you have posted..  Hope that helps you.

Comment: If I get some time to play with it I'll see if I can come up with anything. The answer I linked to seemed pretty straightforward but not enough for me to answer anything without some time to see what's actually going on.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your data structure correctly, you could do something very similar to your *"WITHOUT USING PIVOT()"* T-SQL query:

```
// Test data.
var kb_article_custom_data = new CustomData[] {
    new CustomData() { article_id = 1, custom_data_key = "article_problem", custom_data_value = "when you try ... 1"},
    new CustomData() { article_id = 1, custom_data_key = "article_cause", custom_data_value = "the issues may occur ... 1"},
    new CustomData() { article_id = 1, custom_data_key = "article_solution", custom_data_value = "1. Click start, then ... 1"},
    new CustomData() { article_id = 2, custom_data_key = "article_problem", custom_data_value = "when you try ... 2"},
    new CustomData() { article_id = 2, custom_data_key = "article_cause", custom_data_value = "the issues may occur ... 2"},
    new CustomData() { article_id = 2, custom_data_key = "article_solution", custom_data_value = "1. Click start, then ... 2"},
    new CustomData() { article_id = 3, custom_data_key = "article_problem", custom_data_value = "when you try ... 3"},
    //new CustomData() { article_id = 3, custom_data_key = "article_cause", custom_data_value = "the issues may occur ... 3"},
    new CustomData() { article_id = 3, custom_data_key = "article_solution", custom_data_value = "1. Click start, then ... 3"},
};

var kb_article = new Article[] {
    new Article() { article_id = 1, article_title = "Title ... 1"},
    new Article() { article_id = 2, article_title = "Title ... 2"},
    new Article() { article_id = 3, article_title = "Title ... 3"},
};

// Query resembling your "without pivot" query.
var result =
    from article in kb_article
    join custom in kb_article_custom_data on article.article_id equals custom.article_id into ac
    select new {
        id = article.article_id,
        title = article.article_title,
        problem = ac.Where(x => x.custom_data_key == "article_problem").Select(x => x.custom_data_value).FirstOrDefault(x => x != null),
        cause = ac.Where(x => x.custom_data_key == "article_cause").Select(x => x.custom_data_value).FirstOrDefault(x => x != null),
        solution = ac.Where(x => x.custom_data_key == "article_solution").Select(x => x.custom_data_value).FirstOrDefault(x => x != null)
    };

foreach (var r in result)
    Console.WriteLine(r);
```

Which produces the following output:

```
{ id = 1, title = Title ... 1, problem = when you try ... 1, cause = the issues may occur ... 1, solution = 1. Click start, then ... 1 }
{ id = 2, title = Title ... 2, problem = when you try ... 2, cause = the issues may occur ... 2, solution = 1. Click start, then ... 2 }
{ id = 3, title = Title ... 3, problem = when you try ... 3, cause = , solution = 1. Click start, then ... 3 }
```

If you want to filter by a specific `article_id`, you need to add a `where` clause:

```
var id = 1;
var result =
    from article in kb_article
    where article.article_id == id
    join custom in kb_article_custom_data on article.article_id equals custom.article_id into ac
    select new
    {
        id = article.article_id,
        title = article.article_title,
        problem = ac.Where(x => x.custom_data_key == "article_problem").Select(x => x.custom_data_value).FirstOrDefault(x => x != null),
        cause = ac.Where(x => x.custom_data_key == "article_cause").Select(x => x.custom_data_value).FirstOrDefault(x => x != null),
        solution = ac.Where(x => x.custom_data_key == "article_solution").Select(x => x.custom_data_value).FirstOrDefault(x => x != null)
    };
```

Producing the following output:

```
{ id = 1, title = Title ... 1, problem = when you try ... 1, cause = the issues may occur ... 1, solution = 1. Click start, then ... 1 }
```

Comment: Alex, thank you for the reply.  I've got your code working.  How do I pass a parameter into the WHERE clause so that I'm only bringing back articles related to article_number=@id?

Comment: @paparush, by adding a `where article.article_id == id` clause after the `from article in kb_article` line.

Comment: Thanks. The code is returning 3 rows.  [0] id=960, Cause=null, Problem="When you try...", Solution=null. [1]id=960, Cause="The Issue may occur...", Problem=null, Solution = null.  [2] id=960, Cause=null, Problem=null, Solution = "Click start then..."

Comment: @paparush, added a `not null` for the `FirstOrDefault` selection & an example for the `where`.

Comment: Thanks again.  After adding the != null, I'm still getting the 3 rows back, same as above.  It seems like I'd need to include a  GROUP statement.

Comment: I finally got the syntax right. I've posted the solution above. Thanks again for looking at this.

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

```
 var query =
                        from a in custdata
                        join b in kbase on a.article_id equals b.article_id into ac
                        where (a.custom_data_key == "article_problem" || a.custom_data_key == "article_cause" || a.custom_data_key == "article_solution") && a.article_id == id
                        group a by new { a.article_id} into abc
                        select new
                        {
                            ID = abc.Key.article_id,
                            Cause = abc.Where(a =>a.custom_data_key == "article_cause").Select(a => a.custom_data_value).FirstOrDefault(x => x != null),
                            Problem = abc.Where(a => a.custom_data_key == "article_problem").Select(a => a.custom_data_value).FirstOrDefault(x => x != null),
                            Solution = abc.Where(a => a.custom_data_key == "article_solution").Select(a => a.custom_data_value).FirstOrDefault(x => x != null)
                        };
```