# Transform a table format in Linq C#

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

This is my simple query:

```
<table class="table-bordered">
        @foreach (var data in Model.TableEE.Select(x => new { Month = x.Month, Year = x.EmpIn, Amount = x.EmpOut }))
        {
            <tr>
                <td>@data.Month</td>
                <td>@data.Year</td>
                <td>@data.Amount</td>
            </tr>
        }
</table>
```

The result from above query:

[image]

I need to transform into this format:

```
         |Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul   |Aug   |Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec|
CY2015   | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0    | 0    | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
CY2016   | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |165947|165947| 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
```

Can anyone help me to achieve this?
Thanks!

Comment: And what have you tried yourself? It is a very simple task.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to Pivot data using LINQ?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/167304/is-it-possible-to-pivot-data-using-linq)

Answer (score 0):

Now I Understand what exactly you are looking for, and you will have to do a `GroupBy(y => y.Mounth)` and an `OrderBy(y => y.Year)`. Then you will be able to present data in the format you want.

Sorry that I don't write the entire snippent of code, but I don't have your structure so I will not be sure it will compile.

Comment: your code only change rows to columns, but it is different format with my question

Comment: @SuhandyChow sorry for the long time to answer, I have read the question wrong at the first time.