# Generating list in a following format

Tags: c#, linq

I have scenario where i will receive the header names (for creating text file) from database. 
The list will be like

```
DeptId TeacherId StudentId testname testvalue

  101   1           501     A         85
  101   1           501     B         90
  101   1           502     A         80
  101   1           502     B         75
  101   2           502     A         80
  101   2           502     B         84
  102   1           503     A         56
  102   1           503     B         60
```

Assuming that the number of test will be same ( A & B)
The output should be like

```
DeptId TeacherId StudentId   A   B
101     1         501       85   90
101     1         502       80   75
101     2         502       80   84
102     1         503       56   60
```

Comment: And what is your actual question? What exactly are you having problems with? What have you tried so far, and where exactly are you stuck?

Comment: This is called a pivot.  You can google that to find ways to achieve it in SQL or in code.

Comment: Just look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/167304/is-it-possible-to-pivot-data-using-linq

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this would work

```
var results = from x in context.Tests
              group x by new { x.DeptId, x.StudentId, x.TeacherId } into grp
              select new 
              {
                  grp.Key.DeptId,
                  grp.Key.StudentId,
                  grp.Key.TeacherId,
                  A = grp.FirstOrDefault(x => x.TestName == "A")?.TestValue,
                  B = grp.FirstOrDefault(x => x.TestName == "B")?.TestValue
              };
```

This requires C# 6 for the null-conditional operator `?.`, but you could do this instead

```
A = grp.Where(x => x.TestName == "A").Select(x => x.TestValue).FirstOrDefault();
```

You might also want to filter out other tests with a `where` after the `from` to avoid results were both A and B would end up being `null`, like this

```
where x.TestName == "A" || x.TestName == "B"
```

Of course you could still end up with null values for A and B if the DeptId-StudentId-TeacherId combination only has one of those tests in your DB.

Comment: We are not sure about the test names until we get those from database

Comment: @SillyVolley In that case you could do something like `Tests = grp.ToDictionary(x => x.TestName, x => x.TestValue)` instead.  If you don't know the column names then it's not going to be easy to create them.