# How Datatable use LINQ after groupby then select by some condition to copy to new datatable?

Tags: c#, linq, datatable, group-by

I have a DataTable as follow,

```
SN   NO  NAME
----------------
a1   1   AA12
a1   2   BB34
```

How can I use LINQ let this DataTable group by SN and then select where to fill new table like this?

```
SN   NAME1  NAME2
------------------------
a1   AA12   BB34
```

I try use group by then where ans select by LINQ, but still fail..Can someone help me? Thanks.

Comment: You are creating a pivot, have a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/167304/is-it-possible-to-pivot-data-using-linq

Comment: Is it LONQ or LINQ?

Comment: I'm sorry, my mistake.