# Select data from List<MyClass> where class property is List<double> and show result in DataTable

Tags: c#, list, linq, datatable

I have a class:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public uint ID { get; set; }
    public List<double> Values { get; set; }
}
```

Then, I'm creating a list of class objects:

```
List<MyClass> objects = new List<MyClass>(); // then I add the data to this list
```

Now, I'm need to select data from ***objects*** like:

```
var query = objects.Select(o => new { o.ID, o.Values } ).ToList(); // this example show only ID field in DataTable
```

and convert result to DataTable like this:

```
public DataTable ConvertToDataTable<T>(IList<T> data)
{
    DataTable table = new DataTable();
    PropertyDescriptorCollection properties = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(typeof(T));          

    foreach (PropertyDescriptor prop in properties)
        table.Columns.Add(prop.Name, Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(prop.PropertyType) ?? prop.PropertyType);

    foreach (T item in data)
    {
        DataRow row = table.NewRow();

        foreach (PropertyDescriptor prop in properties)
            row[prop.Name] = prop.GetValue(item) ?? DBNull.Value;

        table.Rows.Add(row);
    }

    return table;
}
```

So, I need to make something like cross-tab query. How can I doing that?

Comment: 1. there are extensions https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datatableextensions.copytodatatable?view=netframework-4.7.2 2. Why not Linq-to-objects 3. Linq to data-table

Comment: @T.S. Please, show example.

Comment: Few different ways to pivot are given: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/167304/is-it-possible-to-pivot-data-using-linq

Comment: @peeyush singh, thank's, but this link does not contains examples with List as class field or List into another List, so this is not work for me.

Comment: Your `query` is just a copy of the original `List` in an anonymous class - what are you really trying to do?

Comment: @NetMage, of course, my class have more fields, than I showed here, but I need to select only two of it.

Comment: Vlad, if you're looking for examples - your question is invalid because now it falls under category: looking for tutorials, books, references, etc. This is what google is for

Comment: @T.S., thank's, but if I found a solution in Google, I would not ask this question.