# Pass rows to columns in consultation with c # Linq

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, linq

sorry for my English, I need your help. I currently receive from the database this:

[image]

But I need to get this with linq, thank you very much for your help. 
the year column can increase

[image]

Edit: Code

```
var res = listaEnIndicaorList.GroupBy(x => new {x.ID_PE, x.ID_JERARQUIA, 
x.ID_INDICADOR})
            .Select(x => new
            {
                id_1 = x.Key.ID_PE,
                id_2 = x.Key.ID_JERARQUIA,
                id_3 = x.Key.ID_INDICADOR,
                Data = x.Select(d => d.ANIO).ToList()
            }).ToList();
```

Comment: I've tried it already but without success, thanks anyway

Comment: Please share so we could help you with that

Comment: The first thing to do when *researching* a problem is to learn the vocabulary.  The kind of query you want is called a pivot query.  Also note that a DB design with serialized column names (id_1, id_2, id_3, Des_1, des_2) is seriously flawed to begin with - it means some important relationships are not present

Comment: @Ňɏssa Pøngjǣrdenlarp 
Thank you for your response, it is an example of what I am working on, and I have basic knowledge of linq, but I am learning and practicing.

Comment: @Julian ok, edit my question.

Comment: a good starting point. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/167304/is-it-possible-to-pivot-data-using-linq

Comment: could you tell us what will be the value of on `2020, 2021, 2022, 2023`

Comment: Thanks @gabriel-llorico, I have updated the images, I would very much appreciate your help or any indication of how I could do it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to Pivot data using LINQ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/167304/is-it-possible-to-pivot-data-using-linq)