# Matrix output in ASP.NET MVC LINQ

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, matrix, pivot-table

I have 3 simple tables

tblQual (ID, QualName)

tblPerson (ID, PersonName)

tblPersonQual (ID, PersonID, QualID, ExpiryDate)

I would like to display a matrix with PersonName down the left, QualName at the top and ExpiryDate in the middle. How do I go about doing this?

I've tried this but no joy.

```
var QualMatrix = from c in db.tblPersonQual
    join q in db.tblQual on c.QualID equals q.ID
    join p in db.tblPerson on c.PersonID equals p.ID
                         group c by c.ID into g
                         select new
                         {
                             rowKey = g.Key,
                             rowData = g.Select(c => new { Qual = q.QualName, Expiry = c.Expiry })
                         };
```

In terms of output view something similar to this

[image]

Comment: LINQ Pivot query, this might be helpful for you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/167304/is-it-possible-to-pivot-data-using-linq

Answer (score 0):

As my understanding, you want to display a matrix with QualName, ExpiryDate and QualName. We can use the same query by just modifying `group` `by` clause.

```
var QualMatrix = from c in db.tblPersonQual
                 join q in db.tblQual on c.QualID equals q.ID
                 join p in db.tblPerson on c.PersonID equals p.ID
                 group new { q.QualName,p.PersonName} by new { c.ID,c.ExpiryDate } into g
                 select new
                 {
                       QualName=g.Select(e=>e.QualName).FirstOrDefault(),
                       ExpirtyDate=g.Key.Expiry,
                       PersonName=g.Select(e=>e.PersonName).FirstOrDefault(),
                 };
```

Hopefully, This will fulfil your requirement.

Comment: Hi thanks for replying, so how would I display this data output in a matrix on view (razor)? So having each person listed on the left hand side, all the quals listed across the top and expiry date as the value in the middle?

Comment: Can you share your matrix mockup design so that I understand well?