# How to use pivot in LINQ efficiently?

Tags: c#, linq, pivot, odata

I searched for how to do pivot data with LINQ and found [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/167304/is-it-possible-to-pivot-data-using-linq)

I am trying apply this for my OData API service.

Table Data has composite key as { Id, Name, DataType }.

Table Analyses has key as Id.

So, I try this code, and everything works fine:

```
var pv = _context.Data.GroupBy(g => new { g.Id, g.Name, g.DataType })
            .Select(s => new
            {
                Id = s.Key.Id,
                Name = s.Key.Name,
                DataType = s.Key.DataType,
                C1 = s.Where(w => w.Component == "C1").Max(s => s.Value),
                C2 = s.Where(w => w.Component == "C2").Max(s => s.Value),
                C3 = s.Where(w => w.Component == "C3").Max(s => s.Value),
                .
                .
                .
                .
                .
                C98 = s.Where(w => w.Component == "C98").Max(s => s.Value),
                C99 = s.Where(w => w.Component == "C99").Max(s => s.Value),
                C100 = s.Where(w => w.Component == "C100").Max(s => s.Value)
            });
var rs = pv.Where(w => w.Id == 1);
```

But when I try to join with another table, it run like forever:

```
var pv = _context.Data.GroupBy(g => new { g.Id, g.Name, g.DataType })
            .Select(s => new
            {
                Id = s.Key.Id,
                Name = s.Key.Name,
                DataType = s.Key.DataType,
                C1 = s.Where(w => w.Component == "C1").Max(s => s.Value),
                C2 = s.Where(w => w.Component == "C2").Max(s => s.Value),
                C3 = s.Where(w => w.Component == "C3").Max(s => s.Value),
                .
                .
                .
                .
                .
                C98 = s.Where(w => w.Component == "C98").Max(s => s.Value),
                C99 = s.Where(w => w.Component == "C99").Max(s => s.Value),
                C100 = s.Where(w => w.Component == "C100").Max(s => s.Value)
            }).Join(_context.Analyses, p => p.Id, a => a.Id, (p, a) => new 
               {
                   Id = p.Id,
                   Name = p.Name,
                   DataType = p.DataType,
                   AnalysName = a.AnalysName,
                   C1 = p.C1,
                   .
                   .
                   C100 = p.C100,
               });
var rs = pv.Where(w => w.Id== 1);
```

The less aggregate column (C1, C2...) the faster the query. So, is there anyway I can make this? Any advice for the query or another way to approach this will be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Try to replace aggregations with this pattern `s.Max(s => s.Component == "C1"  ? 0 : s.Value) `

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv Thanks for you reply, I think you mean != instead of ==? And it still running too slow.

Comment: Actually similar queries are automatically generated by PivotGrids, for example DevExpress. Maybe you need such control?